# PostgreSQL update query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update table in my database. For sake of simplicity lets assume that table's name is `tab` and it has 2 columns: `id (PRIMARY KEY, NOT NULL)` and `col (UNIQUE VARCHAR(300))`. I need to update table this way:

```
id                    col
----------------------------------------------------
1                     'One two three'
2                     'One twothree'
3                     'One two       three'
4                     'Remove white spaces'
5                     'Something'
6                     'Remove whitespaces '
```

to:

```
id                    col
----------------------------------------------------
1                     'Onetwothree'
2                     'Removewhitespaces'
3                     'Something'
```

`Id` numbers and order of the rows after update is not important and can be different. I use PostgreSQL. Some of the columns are FOREIGN KEYs. That's why dropping `UNIQUE` constraint from `col` would be troublesome.

Comment: Actually, you want to remove the duplicates that would be created after removing whitespaces, right?

Comment: How did you get foreign key on non primary key column?

Comment: @DavidLevel: It's defined `UNIQUE`, that is sufficient for a FK constraint referenc**ing** `col`. For an FK constraint pointing the other way, you don't need either. Unfortunately, the Q is unclear about the direction of the FK constraint.

Answer (score 2):

I think just using `replace` in this format will do what you want.

```
update tab
set col = replace(col, ' ', '');
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/50ace/4) for it.

Comment: replace function is not global, it will just remove the first whitespace isn't it? But good link I didn't know it

Comment: In postgres documnentation it says: *Replace all occurrences in string of substring from with substring to* .. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Yeah it worked but if it's something different than whitespace he will have a lot of lines to write, isn't it? I tell you that because I already tried it in a script before.

Comment: SELECT regexp_replace(myfield, '[ \t\n\r]*', '', 'g')
    FROM mytable; This will works I guess. I deleted my answer because I forgot about the unique constraint on col

Comment: David - that's exactly the same what I tried to do. But you forget that `col` is UNIQUE and it would NOT work because after `SELECT regexp_replace(myfield, '[ \t\n\r]*', '', 'g')` you got UNIQUE constraint error.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the non-descriptive column name `id`, even if some half-wit ORMs are in the habit of doing that. I use `tab_id` instead for this demo.

I interpret your description this way: You have other tables with FK columns pointing *to* `tab.col`. Like table `child1` in my example below.

To clean up the mess, do all of this **in a single session** to preserve the temporary table I use. Better yet, do it all in a **single transaction**.

1. Update all **referencing tables** to have all referencing rows point to the **"first"** (unambiguously! - how ever you define that) in a set of going-to-be duplicates in `tab`.

   Create a translation table `up` to be used for all updates:

   ```
   CREATE TEMP TABLE up AS
   WITH t AS (
       SELECT tab_id, col, replace(col, ' ', '') AS col1
            ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY replace(col, ' ', '')
                                ORDER BY  tab_id) AS rn
       FROM   tab
       )
   SELECT b.col AS old_col, a.col AS new_col
   FROM  (SELECT * FROM t WHERE rn = 1) a
   JOIN  (SELECT * FROM t WHERE rn > 1) b USING (col1);
   ```

   Then update all your referencing tables.

   ```
   UPDATE child1 c
   SET    col = up.new_col
   FROM   up
   WHERE  c.col = up.old_col;

   --  more tables?
   ```

   [-> SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c70fc/1)

   Now, all references point to the "first" in a group of dupes, and you have got your license to kill the rest.
2. **Remove duplicate rows** except the first from `tab`.

   ```
   DELETE FROM tab t
   USING  up
   WHERE  t.col = up.old_col
   ```
3. Be sure that all referencing FK constraints have the **`ON UPDATE CASCADE`** clause.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE child1 DROP CONSTRAINT child1_col_fkey;

   ALTER TABLE child1  ADD CONSTRAINT child1_col_fkey FOREIGN KEY (col)
   REFERENCES tab (col)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE;

   -- more tables?
   ```
4. Sanitize your values by **removing white space**

   ```
   UPDATE tab
   SET    col = replace(col, ' ', '');
   ```

   This only takes care of good old space characters (ASCII value 32, Unicode U+0020). Do you have others?

All FK constraints should be pointing to `tab.tab_id` to begin with. Your tables would be smaller and faster and all of this would be easier.

Comment: The scenario may not match the OP's but I find it important that you've stated it clearly and it makes sense (to me anyway), as does the approach to solving the issue. On a secondary note in your answer, why do you say that naming a column simply as `id` is something that the OP *shouldn't* do rather than something that you yourself *wouldn't* do? I mean, isn't that a matter of personal preference (or of corporate policy at most)? To me, for instance, `customer.id` would be just as clear as `customer.customer_id`. The latter *may* be somewhat beneficial down the road, but so may the former.

Comment: @AndriyM: Well, to some degree it's always a matter of opinion, of course. But using non-descriptive names like `id` is *almost always* bad style. When you join a couple of tables in a query - which is what you do *a lot* in relational databases - you end up with multiple columns all named `id`. That's not helpful and leads to mistakes. I have dealt with a few of those cases here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it much easier then *Erwin*. I don't have SQL on my computer to test it but something like that worked for me:

```
DELETE FROM tab WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT id, col, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY regexp_replace(col, '[ \t\n]*', '')) AS c WHERE c > 1;
    )
)

UPDATE tab SET col = regexp_replace(col, '[ \t\n]*', '');
```

Comment: How could it work if you were unable even to test it? What exactly did you mean by *worked for me*?